# If $2(bc^2+ca^2+ab^2) = b^2c+c^2a+a^2b+3abc, $ then prove that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, triangles, sum-of-squares-method

In a triangle $ABC,$ if $2(bc^2+ca^2+ab^2) = b^2c+c^2a+a^2b+3abc, $ then prove that triangle

$ABC$ is equilateral

$\displaystyle \frac{2(bc^2+ca^2+ab^2)}{abc} = \frac{b^2c+c^2a+a^2b+3abc}{abc}$

$\displaystyle 2\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c}\right)+3$

let $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} = x,\frac{b}{c}=y,\frac{c}{a}=z$

so $\displaystyle 2(x+y+z) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+3$

wan,t be able to proceed after that, could some help me

Comment: This was in the IMO Longlist in 1980s. Will dig it out for ya

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h370150p2039367

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle we may write $(a,b,c) = (y+z,z+x,x+y)$
with $x,y,z>0$.  The difference between the two sides is then
$$
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \; + \; x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x
- 2 (xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2).
$$
By cyclic symmetry we may assume $x \geq z$ and $y \geq z$, and write
$x = (1 + \alpha) z$ and $y = (1 + \beta) z$ with $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$
to find $z^3$ times
$$
2(\alpha^2 - \alpha\beta + \beta^2) + \beta(\alpha-\beta)^2 + \alpha^3,
$$
in which each term is nonnegative, and all are zero **iff**
$\alpha = \beta = 0$ $-$ which in turn is equivalent to $x=y=z$,
and thus $a=b=c$, so triangle $ABC$ is equilateral as claimed.
$\Box$

[*Added later*: The solution above applies a general technique for such 
problems; but I see that for the present question 
**Hari Shankar** posted (in a comment) a link to an
[AoPS item](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h370150p2039367)
that gives an even simpler conclusion that retains the cyclic symmetry:
$$
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \; + \; x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x
- 2 (xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2) = x(x-z)^2 + y(y-x)^2 + z (z-y)^2,
$$
again with all terms nonnegative; so equality implies that
they all vanish and the rest follows as before.  That link also
gives the example $(a:b:c) = (10:3:24)$ of a rational point on the cubic
$2(bc^2 + ca^2 + ab^2) = b^2c + c^2a + a^2b + 3abc$ with positive variables
that do not satisfy the triangle inequality.]

Comment: I think, your solution is very ugly. See my solution.

Comment: Your solution is essentially the same as the AoPS solution that I quote
at the end of my answer
(except that you kept everything in terms of the original $a,b,c$, 
making the displayed formulas longer).  That's prettier than the
first solution I gave (though surely it's not all *that* ugly...),
but this solution illustrates a general technique, and thus does not
attempt to exploit simplifications available for this particular instance
of this class of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Because 
$$0=\sum\limits_{cyc}(2b^2a-a^2b-abc)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-abc-(b^3-2b^2a+a^2b))=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab)-\sum\limits_{cyc}b(a-b)^2=$$
$$=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)-b\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+c-b).$$
Id est, the given it's
$$(a-b)^2(a+c-b)+(b-c)^2(b+a-c)+(c-a)^2(c+b-a)=0,$$
which says that $a=b=c$.

Done!

Comment: Right; this is again the AoPS solution.

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies It's my own solution.

Comment: I do not dispute this, but then you've rediscovered it.

Answer (score -1):

$x+y+z\geq 3(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$,when $x=y=z$ ,equal sign is established.So:$$2\sum\frac{c}{a}\geq\sum\frac{c}{a}+3$$ i.e.$$\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}$$Without loss of generality, we assume:$c\geq b\geq a$,so $\frac1{a}\geq\frac1{b}\geq\frac1{c},$then we have:$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}\leq\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{a}{b},$$so $a=b=c$.I'm using an incomplete sort to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Note that the RHS sum is $\sum\dfrac{a}{c}$.

Comment: I will make it clearer

Comment: but Zeo RHS present $\sum \frac{a}{c}$ and you wrote $\sum \frac{c}{a}$

Comment: Since neither the original equality nor your inequality is symmetric on $a,b,c$ you can't assume WLOG that $c\geq b\geq a$. Also, you prove that $\sum \dfrac{c}{a} \geq 3$, not that $2\sum \dfrac{c}{a} \geq \sum \dfrac{a}{c} + 3$.

Comment: @Darth Geek  I think you should check it again.I prove that$B+3=2A\geqA+3$,so,$B\geqA$

Comment: @Zuo $x+y+z \geq 3(xyz)^{1/3}$ proves that $x+y+z \geq 3$, i.e. $\sum \dfrac{c}{a} \geq 3$. With equality iff $a = b = c$. That doesn't prove that $2\sum \dfrac{c}{a} \geq \sum \dfrac{a}{c} + 3$. Incidently, you still write $\sum \dfrac{c}{a}$ on the RHS, where it's supposed to be $\sum \dfrac{a}{c}$ instead.

Comment: Please look carefully

Comment: Right, I see what you are trying to do now. You might want to add some more text so it's clearer. However, since the inequality you try to prove is not symmetric on $a,b,c$ you can't assume $c\geq b\geq a$ WLOG. In fact, if $b \leq c \leq a$ then you should get the opposite inequality: $$\dfrac{a}{c} + \dfrac{b}{a} + \dfrac{c}{b} \geq \dfrac{c}{a} + \dfrac{b}{c} + \dfrac{a}{b}$$

Comment: Also, if $a = b < c$ then indeed $c\geq b\geq a$ and
$$\dfrac{a}{c} + \dfrac{b}{a} + \dfrac{c}{b} =\dfrac{a}{c} + 1 +  \dfrac{c}{a} = \dfrac{c}{a} + \dfrac{b}{c} + \dfrac{a}{b}$$ but you can't deduce from that that $a = b = c$.